# How to resize QTableWidget on Widget by dragging its corner

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, drag, qtablewidget

I want to resize `QTableWidget` by dragging bottom right corner like following screen shot. How to do this? Here is my code.

code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget
week = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thr", "fri", "sat", "sun"]
app = QApplication([])
mainWidget = QWidget()
tableWidget = QTableWidget(mainWidget)
tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
tableWidget.setColumnCount(7)
tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(week)
mainWidget.show()
```

[image]

thanks.

Comment: Hi, you have to push your QTableWidget in a layout (QGridLayout/QVerticalLayout/QHorizontalLayout), and put your layout in your mainwindow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is using a `QSizeGrip` in a layout inside the table widget :

```
tableWidget->setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow);

QSizeGrip * sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(tableWidget);

QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout(tableWidget);
layout->addWidget(sizeGrip, 0,0,1,1,Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight);
```

The `QSizeGrip` class provides a resize handle for resizing top-level windows. When you set the widget flag `Qt::SubWindow`, then the user can resize it using the size grip.

Comment: Setting a layout on a widget not meant to contain other widgets, such as a `QTableWidget`, is essentially a bug. You have no guarantees that the widget doesn't use a layout that you've just happily replaced. What you show is a nice hack, but it shouldn't be used. Instead, you can write a short event filter for resize events that will keep the size grip properly aligned.